# select multiple array elements javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to select multiple array elements at once?

I have this code:

```
var my_array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
```

I would like to select 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, 9th element from the array at the same time, something like this

```
my_array[0,2,4,6,8];
```

Comment: You're going to have to loop or individually assign them. Subscripts don't work that way

Comment: In this particular case you may want to look at the n-th-child css selector

Comment: That's not an array BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way, if you must use JavaScript, would be to set up a simple function, to which you pass the array and the indices:

```
function modifyStylesOf(arr, indices, prop, newValue) {

    // here we filter the array to retain only those array elements
    // are present in the supplied 'indices' array:
    arr.filter(function(el, index) {

      // if the index of the current element is present in the
      // array of indices the index will be zero or greater,
      // so those elements will be retained (as the assessment
      // will be true/truthy:
      return indices.indexOf(index) !== -1;

    // we iterate over the retained Array elements using
    // Array.prototype.forEach():
    }).forEach(function (el) {

      // and here we update the passed-in property
      // to the passed-in value:
      el.style[prop] = newValue;
    });
}
```

Then call with:

```
// here we use Array.from() to convert the nodeList/HTMLCollection
// into an Array:
modifyStylesOf(Array.from(c), [1,3,5,7,9], 'webkitTextFillColor', 'transparent');
```

```js
function modifyStylesOf(arr, indices, prop, newValue) {
  arr.filter(function(el, index) {
    return indices.indexOf(index) !== -1;
  }).forEach(function(el) {
    el.style[prop] = newValue;
  });
}

var c = document.querySelectorAll('body div');

modifyStylesOf(Array.from(c), [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 'webkitTextFillColor', 'orange');
```

```css
div {
  counter-increment: divCount;
}
div::before {
  content: counter(divCount, decimal-leading-zero);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Bear in mind, though, that your original selector included all childNodes (which necessarily includes `textNode`s, and HTML comment nodes (among, potentially, others); whereas it seems you want only `HTMLElement`s; for that I'd strongly suggest using a slightly different means of selection:

```
// the Element.children property will retrieve only
// element nodes:
var c = document.getElementById("nc-2").children;
```

Or:

```
// using document.querySelectorAll(), with a CSS
// selector can select only elements (as with CSS),
// though I'd suggest something more specific than
// the universal selector ('*') to specify which
// child elements to select:
var c = document.querySelectorAll('#nc-2 > *');
```

Further, though without seeing your HTML it's rather hard to be particularly precise, it *seems* that you're trying to select only the odd-numbered indices of the `childNode`s, which lends itself to using CSS only to achieve your goal. In your specific case that would be:

```
#nc-2 > :nth-child(odd) {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```css
body > div:nth-child(odd) {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: orange;
}

div {
  counter-increment: divCount;
}

div::before {
  content: counter(divCount, decimal-leading-zero);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: ...or eventually using CSS and `#nc-2 *:htn-child(odd)`

Comment: @Roko: yeah, it took me longer than anticipated to run through and verify the function, create the demo and then point out the issues with using `childNodes` versuse `children`...CSS added (finally)! :)

Comment: Thanks man ,work's perfectly,this is the first answer that I tested and work's just as I wanted so I won't look at the other answers but thanks a lot Dashing Dev,Oscar Gomez Alcaniz,Explosion Pills.

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way to achieve this nowadays is to use the map function:

```
[0,2,4,6,8].map(x=>my_array[x]);
```

The trick is to call the map function on an array of the desired indexes. An array map function will return an array of the same length as the array it is called on. The callback function inside the map function (`x=>my_array[x]`) then returns the value of `my_array` for each of the desired indexes.

Comment: can also add `.filter(x=> x !== undefined)` to remove `undefined` elements .. so something like this `[0,2,4,6,8].map(x=>my_array[x]).filter(x=> x !== undefined)`

Comment: that's such an awkward solution compared to simple multi indexing :D

Answer (score 2):

```js
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
var myIndices = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8];

var result = [];
myIndices.forEach(i => result.push(myArray[i]));

console.log(result);
```

(undefined because some of these indices are off the end of the data).

Comment: If the array and indices are large, is it more efficient to create the result array with a defined length?

Answer (score 0):

This is where something like jQuery can actually come in handy because it can operate on collections:

```
$("#nc-2").children(":odd").css("-webkit-text-fill-color", "transparent");
```

You can do this without jQuery of course, but you have to loop yourself.

```
document.querySelectorAll("#nc-2 > :nth-child(odd)").forEach(
  elem => elem.style.WebkitTextFillColor = "transparent"
);
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#nc-2 > :nth-child(odd)").forEach(elem => elem.style.backgroundColor = "purple")
```

```css
div > div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nc-2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can loop through the code like this below:

```
var c = document.getElementById("nc-2").childNodes;
for(var count=0; count < c.length; c++){
  //this condition is used to test for odd indexes
  if(count%2 !== 0){      
    c[count].style.webkitTextFillColor="transparent"; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a good old `forEach`:

```
document.getElementById("nc-2").childNodes.forEach(function (node, index) {
  if ([1,3,5,7,9].indexOf(index) >= 0) { node.style.webkitTextFillColor="transparent"; }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After you convert your Node List into an array like `var childNodes = [...nodeList]` then the rest is like this;

```js
var childNodes = ["child0","child1","child2","child3","child4","child5","child6","child7","child8","child9"],
 selectedNodes = childNodes.reduce((p,c,i) => i & 1 ? p.concat(c) : p,[]);
console.log(selectedNodes);
```

Note: `i & 1` is `true` when i is odd.

Answer (score 0):

or the filter function

```js
const indexes = [0,2,4,6,8];
    
my_array.filter((v,i)=>indexes.includes(indexes));
```

although this is O(n*m) so the map function from @tommyleejones is faster since that doesn't have to compare values but rather uses indexes to its only O(n)